# HTML Entity decoding mixing with BIG5 characters, convert to UTF-8 using Perl

Tags: perl, character-encoding, html-entities, html-encode, chinese-locale

My Perl script and data input file are in BIG5 Chinese encoding.

The string data contains HTML entity, eg. Japanese characters

The result displays perfectly when viewing on the browser.

But for further data manipulation, I need to convert them all into UTF-8

eg.

From BIG5 encoding

`一&#12392;三`

To UTF-8 encoding

`一と三`

Here's the code I've tried:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Encode qw/encode decode/;
use HTML::Entities;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

$str = "&#12392;";
$str = encode('utf8', decode("big5",$str));
print "$str\n";
decode_entities($str);
print "$str\n";

$str2 = "一&#12392;三";
$str2 = encode('utf8', decode("big5",$str2));
print "$str2\n";
decode_entities($str2); # where the issue is
print "$str2\n";
```

Here's the result after running the above code.

```
&#12392;
と
一&#12392;三
ä¸とä¸
```

Please note the script itself is also saved as BIG5 encoding.

After `decode_entities($str2);` it seems that it's trying to decode the Chinese characters in UTF-8 too, that's causing the issue.

How do I fix this issue?  Or limit to the decode_entities() only applying to `&xxxxx;` pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you mix decode_entities which outputs an utf8 string (`utf8::is_utf8` returns true)  with a raw string (`utf8::is_utf8` returns false) consisting of an octet stream which could be interpreted as utf8. Instead you should combine either raw strings or utf8 strings.

The following works by first encoding your string from big5 to an utf8 string, then replacing the HTML encodings and then finally converting everything to a raw string representing utf8 characters:

```
$str2 = "一&#12392;三";
$str2 = decode("big5",$str2);  # big5 to internal utf8 -> utf8::is_utf8($str2) is true
decode_entities($str2);        # decode HTML entities
$str2 = encode('utf8',$str2);  # internal utf8 to raw bytes, utf8::is_utf8($str2) is false
```

Comment: Great, it's working on my test sample.  But after running a few more test data, I find that some characters don't work, and I couldn't figure out why.  Please see if you can get it to work with this string `$str2 = "&#23947;一&#12392;三&#20870;";` Output should be `嶋一と三円` but now the first and last characters become ? mark

Comment: These HTML Entities characters do show up properly if using my original code `$str2 = encode('utf8', decode("big5",$str2));` (but with other scrambled Chinese characters)

Comment: @KDX: your example gives `嶋一と三円` for me, so it works at least for me. Tried with perl versions 5.22.1, 5.12.5 and even 5.8.9 with a current version of `HTML::Entities`. I have no idea what you are using nor what your code exactly looks like. I've just set `$str2 = "&#23947;一&#12392;三&#20870;"` in my code example.

Comment: My hosting is running Perl 5.12.4 and `HTML::Entities` is showing as 3.69.  I'm using the exact test code you wrote with the `use` declaration in my  original question.  I find it strange because these very same characters do show up if using `$str2 = encode('utf8', decode("big5",$str2));` What versions are you running in your test environment?

Comment: @KDX: HTML::Entities is 3.69 but the actual implementation of decode_entities is done in some C code in HTML::Parser.  Version of HTML::Parser is 3.72 in all cases.

Comment: I don't quite get it.  Do I need to use HTML::Parser in the code?  The string data I'm going to process doesn't contain any HTML, but only plain text containing data field and delimiters. I checked with `perl -MHTML::Parser -e 'print $HTML::Parser::VERSION';` and it's giving me 3.69 too.  Is Perl version going to make a difference?  Thanks.

Comment: @KDX: [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities) is part of the HTML::Parser distribution. The function decode_entities is not implemented inside the HTML::Entities module but in same other file ([util.c](https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.72/util.c)) and thus the version of the HTML::Entities module itself does not matter.  Perl version might make a difference but in this case I doubt it since it works for me with current HTML::Parser distribution and Perl 5.8.9.

Comment: In this case, Do you suggest me upgrading HTML::Parser from 3.69 to 3.72 where the decode_entities in `util.c` will be up-to-date?  It seems like to me only certain HTML Entities are not converting, else it works in most of the cases.

Comment: @KDX: I would give it a try.